# Do electrical circuit systems break down without use?

Tags: electrical

I have no knowledge whatsoever about electrical issues so please bear with me! I am holding my wedding at a very old family estate that has not been used in a  few years. My planner questioned whether the electric system could “wear down” because no one has used the outlets in so long. We will be having 30 people stay in the house as well as hair and makeup (so hair dryers and lighting etc) the morning of.

Is that a thing / should I be concerned about the electrical system or are we completely off base here? Thanks for your help!

Comment: How modern is the system? I think overall system age/condition is your concern, rather than that the system is somehow stale from under-use.

Comment: Electrical circuit wires themselves do not "wear down". However the outlet socket contacts could get tarnished or corroded which could be a problem. What can be a much bigger issue is that rodents of various types like to chew the insulation off of the electrical wires and this could lead to shorts or arcing which could lead to a fire.

Comment: An electrical system usually does not wear down if used or not.  A system can be damaged by rodents and sometimes humidity can cause corrosion if not used(switches and outlets), so it should be checked before using.  Would probably want an Electrician to go over it, instead of just someone turning a switch on to see if it works.

Comment: It is going to be extremely hard to provide an analysis  of the wiring and other electrical components in an aging system that has not seen regular maintenance over the SE Q&A Format. It is suggested that you get a home inspector type person to go out to this property and have a general look around.

Comment: Would think also your insurance will insist on an recent electrical inspection.

Comment: If by unused for a few years, you mean no parties or no one has been in the estate for a few years?  An empty house/estate for a few years can have a lot wrong with it, including electrical, plumbing, and water.

Comment: Where are you on this planet, and how old is the place overall?

Answer (score 2):

To answer your question... no.  Electrical circuits do not break down if they're not used.  Most common wiring is made of copper and doesn't break down over time.  Some wiring can be  aluminum but again, it doesn't break down.

However, to expand.  The connection points can corrode overtime, especially in moist environments, and create connection problems in outlets, switches and light sockets.  Depending on the connections you can clean these up with some steel wool or in bad cases get new switches, outlets, etc...  If you don't feel comfortable doing it an electrician is just a phone call away.

As well, animals (rodents such as mice, rats, racoons, etc...) can chew on wiring and cause major problems that you might not see.

Also, depending on the age of the building is the service amperage.  If you don't have enough amps you could be blowing breakers when everyone is using their hair dryer at the same time or the DJ/Band (if you are having one) starts plugging in their equipment.  Lots of older homes have two or three rooms connected together on the same circuit so this could be a very annoying problem.

So while the circuits do not break down, you can have a host of other problems.